# Can I turn my external USB HDD and 3.5mm audio in jack into a wireless Network?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

I am from Bangalore, India. 
I’ve, a USB 320GB external Hard Disc Drive, a Mi-Fi Router, 2.1 computer speaker and  iPad/iphone/laptop.

I want to read/write files like Photos, music and videos of my external HDD in my iPad/phone/laptop over Wi-Fi. Also I want to connect my speaker with my ipad or iphone or laptop through wirelessly.

Is there any such device which can fulfill my requirement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your router is at all modern, it can run Linux. Install dd-wrt and configure it to expose the USB disk to the local network. As for audio, you need a DAC chip on the device you're planning to connect your speaker to, because the signal is sent over Wi-Fi in digital form and so it needs to be converted to analog form so that you could hear it. I'm pretty sure there are commercial devices out there that can do it, or you could try and connect an external audio card to your router if it has a free USB port, but I don't know how to configure Linux to share it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to Alexei's suggestion would be using a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs) and turning it into a wireless portable media server. Unfortunately I've not done this myself as I'm using my Pi for a different purpose (a wireless security camera). However, a quick Google search shows tons of tutorials on how to go about this.